# Пунктуация в диалогах

Tags: прописная-строчная

Маленькую или большую "и" надо использовать в данном фрагменте:
Он покрутил пальцем у виска:
- Ты не в себе? - и выбежал из комнаты.
С одной стороны, "и выбежал из комнаты" - не относящееся непосредственно к словам героя действие - и надо употребить заглавную "И"; с другой стороны, "Он покрутил пальцем у виска и выбежал из комнаты" - цельное предложение, разрываемое словами персонажа, подлежащее в его второй половине не стоит - и можно использовать маленькую "и". Как правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что правильно надо писать так.

**Он покрутил пальцем у виска: «Ты не в себе?» — и выбежал из комнаты.**

Прямая речь находится внутри слов автора, поэтому она заключается в кавычки, а перед ней ставится двоеточие. После прямой речи, которая заканчивается вопросительным знаком, ставится тире.

Похожее предложение есть в справочнике Лопатина (§ 136).
*Она* [собака] *останавливается. Я повторяю: «Что сказано?» — и держу ее долго на стойке* (Пришвин).

[Знаки препинания при прямой речи](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137)

Comment: Римма, спасибо, но у меня не прямая речь, а диалог, я не знаю, почему не отразился абзац, то есть: с новой строки "Он покрутил...", с новой " - Ты не в себе? - и выбежал из комнаты". Пунктуация при прямой речи и при диалогах примерно сходна, но в указанном Вами предложении слова автора по времени совпадают с проговариваемыми словами, у меня несколько иной случай, действие, описанное в словах автора, шло за словами диалога.

Comment: @РаульАм то есть разбиение цельного предложения на абзацы Вас не смутило?

Comment: Нет, бывает, что слова автора составляют главную фразу, бывает и наоборот, в диалогах основное - слова персонажей, авторская речь является оформлением и с ней можно поступать вольно)); потом по времени действия тоже можно предполагать разбиение на абзацы.